# Prove that the function is not non-expansive

Tags: contraction-mapping

Prove that the function is not non-expansive.

T is non-expansive if

$$ \forall x,y \hspace{3mm} ||Tx-Ty|| \leq ||x-y|| $$

$T(x)= \frac{x sin(x)}{2} \hspace{2mm} 0\leq x \leq \pi $ and $0$ elsewhere. I want to prove this without taking derivatives. My attempt:
\begin{align}
|\frac{x sin(x)}{2}-\frac{y sin(y)}{2}|&=\frac{1}{2}|xsinx-xsiny+xsiny-ysiny| \\
&\leq\frac{1}{2}(|xsinx-xsiny|+|xsiny-ysiny|) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}|x||sinx-siny|+|siny|(|x-y|)\\
&\leq \frac{1}{2}|x||x-y|+\frac{1}{2}|x-y| 
\end{align}

I am unable to proceed further, Can someone please help?

Comment: There seems to be counterexamples: let $x=\pi,\,y=0.9\pi$, [numerical calculation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%7Cxsin%28x%29-ysin%28y%29%7C%2F2+-+%7Cx-y%7C%2C+x%3Dpi%2C+y%3D0.9pi) implies that $|T(x)-T(y)|>|x-y|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Mengchun Zhang, this is not true. In fact, we have $T'(x) < -1$ for $x \in [3,\pi]$ and, therefore, $T$ is not non-expansive.